# Why does increasing the base resistor reduce the voltage gain in the PNP amplifier circuit?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

What will happen to the voltage gain of the below circuit if the resistor R3 is increased?

My initial hunch was that the voltage gain would be reduced, but after working through the problem, I reasoned that:

- Increasing R3 reduces the base current
- Therefore we will get a proportional decrease in collector and emitter current
- Therefore the voltage drop across the load resistor will be smaller
- Therefore Vout will be larger
- Therefore increasing the resistance increases the gain

The answer states that gain will decrease.
I am also a little confused as to why Vout is not taken across the load.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: "Therefore Vout will be larger" How did you find out?

Comment: "why Vout is not taken across the load" I take signal from load resistor all the time if I do not want an inversion (180deg shift).

Comment: One reason to define \$V_{out}\$ as shown is a common node with \$V_{in}\$.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but there's way too much to cover here. This circuit is almost impossible to get "just right", so that the transistor is in its active region, and even if you managed to get all the resistances *just* right for that, the slightest change to R3 and the transistor cuts off or saturates, making any measurement of gain meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Smaller voltage swing on load resistor means smaller swing on Vout. That is the point where you start going wrong.

Comment: Why? I see Vout as essentially being Vsupply - Vcollector. Vsupply is fixed, Vcollector gets smaller, so Vsupply-Vcollector is now larger? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### A bit of history

Your question is perfectly valid; I know this from personal experience. I remember it was sometime in the 80's when my graduate student and I were discussing the slightly more complicated circuit of a *common-emitter amplifier with a resistor in the emitter* (the so-called "emitter degeneration"). Because we reasoned like you, we did not manage to reach the famous gain ratio - Rc/Re. But then we felt where our mistake was and brought it out.

### The problem

The problem is that you now and we then were reasoning with DC large voltage values (Vout, Vc) ​​but the concept of "gain" is defined by small voltage changes (dVout/dVin).

### Implementation

To implement this approach, you have to replace the "load" in your schematic with a constant resistor (Rc) and connect the relatively high-resistance load through another coupling capacitor (C2) in parallel to Rc. The disadvantage of this connection is that the load is "floating".

### Improvement

To solve the problem with the "floating" load, you can ground the one load terminal and connect the other through a coupling capacitor (C2) to the midpoint between Rc and the collector. The benefit of this is that the load is grounded as well as the input source.

Now, it is not the changes of VRc that are applied to the load, but the changes of their complement to Vcc, which are the same.

### More considerations

> Can we essentially say that the intrinsic emitter resistance will be increased as the current reduced?

First let's clarify what "emitter resistance *re*" is.  This is a "formal gimmick" invented for the purposes of the "common base" amplifier stage. It is about the following.

First imagine that the base of the transistor is fixed at a constant voltage, the collector is not connected to Vcc and you apply an input voltage to the emitter. So there is actually a PN junction to which you have applied a voltage. There is a relatively small base current flowing and you have the feeling that it is a relatively large resistance.

Now connect the collector to Vcc. The collector current will exit the emitter and will flow through your input source. Now you (source) will see the same base-emitter voltage but the current is increased to beta*Ib (as though an additional current source Ic is connected in parallel to the base-emitter junction). As a result, you will have the illusion that the base-emitter resistance is *beta* times smaller and name it "re". Figurahively speaking, "re" is a "virtually decreased base-emitter resistance".

> As there is no emitter degeneration, Av = -Rc/re, so the gain is reduced?

It can be said that way, but I prefer to express it through the *transconductance gm* (Av = gm*Rc).

Comment: Can we essentially say that the intrinsic emitter resistance will be increased as the current reduced? As there is no emitter degeneration, Av = -Rc/re, so the gain is reduced?

Comment: @xormapmap, See my last edit.

Comment: @xormapmap Do you have your answer? Because you should not only be able to qualitatively understand why the gain reduces, but to predict the gain as well, quantitatively. (In simulation, anyway, where every part is perfectly what the model says it is.) Knowing how to quantitatively predict it, you will have your answer about why.